# BackboneJS Iterate complex model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a BackboneJS composite model which has 2 attributes;

```
"myAttr1": new MyObj1(model.myAttr1),
"myCollectionAttr": new MyObj2(model.myCollectionAttr)
```

MyObj2 looks like

```
"attr1" : new Base1( ),
"attr2" : new Base2( )
```

Now I want to set an inner level attribute (i.e. an attribute of Base1)...So I iterate and say;

```
self.model.get("myCollectionAttr").each(function(model) {
    model.get("attr1").set('basemodel1attr','Y');
});
```

So Base1 and Base2 model has attributes like basemodel1attr and basemodel2attr

While model.get("attr1") returns me the list of attributes. I cannot use .set() on it.

What is the correct way of doing set on my inner attribute ?

Comment: could you please attach Base1 and Base2 code ?

Comment: have added it...those consist of simple string attributes...

Comment: are Base1 and Base2 instances on Backbone.Model ?

Comment: yes, they are instances of Backbone.Model

Comment: is this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xQLX9/ close to what u'r going to reach

Comment: It is somewhat close...but there are 3 levels...propModel1 is actually an instance of PropertyModel...

Comment: I have just updated the question with more specific requirement...u can check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56414/discussion-between-evgeniy-and-testndtv).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to iterate through the models of your collection and set one specific attribute of that model like this

```
$.each(collection.models, function(i, model){
    model.set('item','new value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up your access. You access the properties of MyObj2 as if it was a Collection. But you stated that MyObj2 is a Model, not a Collection.

```
self.model.get("myCollectionAttr").get("attr1").set("basemodel1attr", "Y");
```

Beside the naming of your properties and the each-loop there is no hint your are really using a collection anywhere. So dont.

If MyObj2 is a Collection you should not try to add 2 different Models to the Collection:

```
window.SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ "attr1": new Base1(), "attr2": new Base2() });
window.SomeColl = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: SomeModel });
```